# How do I make to fit my HTML element for all mobile device (display)?

Tags: android, html, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, mobile

I am very new to mobile applications. I am developing a mobile application using phonegap.
I created a  list view which will fit for small screens i.e,(320*480:mdpi). If I run the same application in big screens i.e,(480*800:mdpi) my list view really looks very small which will properly fit to screen.

Is there any way to fit the html elements for all kind of mobile devices? How can I do the same. Any suggestions?

My list is as follows,

```
 <ul data-role="listview" id="locationList" data-dismissible="false" name="locationList" style="width: 285px; height: 150px; overflow: auto" data-inset="true">
```

Comment: have added meta tag in html?

Comment: I have added the following meta tag:             <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">

Comment: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0/docs/widgets/listviews/ look at samples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why OMG why are you doing this? Every jQuery Mobile widget is already made responsive for every screen resolution, including listview widget. You DON'T need to resize it manually. Think about it, are you really going to have predefined width and height for every screen size, it is ludicrous.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/b433C/

```
<ul data-role="listview" id="locationList" data-dismissible="false" name="locationList" data-inset="true">
    <li><a>Element 1</a></li>
    <li><a>Element 2</a></li>
    <li><a>Element 3</a></li>
    <li><a>Element 4</a></li>                 
</ul>
```

As you can see in this example, listview will resize according to screen size, you don't need to do it by yourself.

Comment: But my problem is it is not a static list view.The values are coming from database. If I get more than 10 values how can I handle it. I need to do too much scrolling right?

Comment: If you get too many database data you will be able to scroll your listview. If you don't want scrolling then just limit number of rows you return from the database.

Comment: Thanks, Will follow your suggestion. How can I do listview scroll?

Comment: It will be available automatically , take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/b433C/1/ . If you want to have fixed header and footer during scrolling then it is something else. I will create you an example if this is what you need.

Answer (score 3):

You need to look at responsive design for HTML pages.

Using meta tags and CSS to dictate particular resolutions.

Here is a [useful tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/build-a-responsive-mobile-friendly-website-from-scratch-dive-into-the-code/).